# When saving objects to a database should I serialize the object or save each property

Tags: c#, sql, oop

I am starting to think about a basic database driven game(rpg).
I am having trouble sorting out how to save the character, his attributes and his items.  For most things where there is only one of them static is fine, but when there are mulitple objects like an inventory for example I am at a bit of a loss.

I decided to put items into a bag object. the bag object can have any where from 5 - 20 slots, each of these slots will reference an item based on unique database ID.  So how do I design the bag table.

BagID | Owner | Slot1 | Slot2 | Slot3 | Slot4 ......

or

BagID | Owner | Contents <-varbinary

Any suggestions?  I was told once that when database programming, one column one data, but I don't like the idea of Slot1 | Slot2 etc...  it just doesn't seem right.

**Edit**

Did I miss this altogether, and it is rightfully the item that should be referencing the Bag.

ItemID | BagID | Slot | Name | .....

Then when you want to find out what is in a bag you would

```
Select * from Items where BagID=10
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Any suggestions?

STANDARD approach since the invention of relational databases way back in the 60ies by cobb is normalization.

BadId, SlotNr, ItemRef

Finished.

Another table has the items.

Note that OwnerId is missing - this is the BagItemMap table. THe BagTable has BagId, OwnerId and possibly other items (total weight etc.)

This is a standard m:n relationshit. WHen you materialize the objects you ahve a Bag object that has the Items as collection.

Comment: So what you are suggesting is what I added in my comments correct?  And of course the bag would be the same, the owner does not know the bag the bag knows the owner?

Comment: THe last is design dependant ;) The owner MAY know the bag, but the other allows multple bags so is more strategically sound.

Answer (score 2):

The persistence strategy depends on your query requirements. If you are looking for an ability to perform operations on more than one character at a time based on one or more of their attributes (e.g. give an extra life to all three-eyed characters, look up all characters with more than five lives, etc.) then you should save individual attributes into their own columns. If a character is always treated as a BLOB, and you have no issues tying the serialization strategy to the data in RDBMS, then use `varbinary`.

Hybrid solutions when you store everything as a BLOB, but also make a subset of attributes available in their separate columns, are also possible. In fact, it is very common to include at least *some* identifying attributes to simplify searches.

Comment: ok I get this thank you, I do not know my needs yet, so I am uncertain if I would ever need to look for all green eyed people.  Though I think I would, or at least would like to keep this option open.  Would I need this at an Item level, I doubt it.

Comment: Actuall this is wrong. I would expect this to be mostly a "nearly no search" object as well as something that is mostly basically handled in memory anyway.

Comment: @TomTom The only case when I needed to implement an all-BLOB solution in practice was when I built a persistent cache. Essentially, the only searchable part was the object's name - everything else was inside the BLOB.

Comment: Well... actually.... Eve Online does a persistence blob for performance reasons;)